# Differences between 'extends' in coffeescript and 'util.inherits' in node.js

Tags: node.js, coffeescript

I am learning Node.js recently. I have a question about the function `util.inherits` in Node.js. Can I use `extends` in coffeescript to replace it? If not, what are the differences between them?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, you can use `extends` in place of it.

As for the differences? Let's start with a look at CoffeeScript:

```
class B extends A
```

Let's look at [the JavaScript the CoffeeScript compiler produces](http://coffeescript.org/#try:class%20B%20extends%20A) for this JavaScript:

```
var B,
  __hasProp = {}.hasOwnProperty,
  __extends = function(child, parent) { for (var key in parent) { if (__hasProp.call(parent, key)) child[key] = parent[key]; } function ctor() { this.constructor = child; } ctor.prototype = parent.prototype; child.prototype = new ctor(); child.__super__ = parent.prototype; return child; };

B = (function(_super) {

  __extends(B, _super);

  function B() {
    return B.__super__.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
  }

  return B;

})(A);
```

So, `__extends` is used to declare the inheritence relationship between `B` and `A`.

Let's restate `__extends` a bit more readably, in CoffeeScript:

```
coffee__extends = (child, parent) ->
  child[key] = val for own key, val of parent

  ctor = ->
    @constructor = child
    return
  ctor.prototype = parent.prototype

  child.prototype = new ctor
  child.__super__ = parent.prototype

  return child
```

(You can check that this is a faithful reproduction by [compiling it back to JavaScript](http://coffeescript.org/#try:coffee__extends%20%3D%20(child%2C%20parent)%20-%3E%0A%20%20child%5Bkey%5D%20%3D%20val%20for%20own%20key%2C%20val%20of%20parent%0A%0A%20%20ctor%20%3D%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%40constructor%20%3D%20child%0A%20%20%20%20return%0A%20%20ctor.prototype%20%3D%20parent.prototype%0A%0A%20%20child.prototype%20%3D%20new%20ctor%0A%20%20child.__super__%20%3D%20parent.prototype%0A%0A%20%20return%20child).)

Here's what's happening:

1. All the keys found directly on `parent` are set on `child`.
2. A new prototype constructor `ctor` is created, with its instances' `constructor` properties set to the child, and its `prototype` set to the parent.
3. The child class's `prototype` is set to an instance of `ctor`. `ctor`'s `constructor` will be set to `child`, and `ctor`'s prototype itself is `parent`.
4. The child class's `__super__` property is set to `parent`'s `prototype`, for use by CoffeeScript's `super` keyword.

[node's documentation](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/util.html#util_util_inherits_constructor_superconstructor) describes `util.inherits` as follows:

> Inherit the prototype methods from one constructor into another. The
>   prototype of constructor will be set to a new object created from
>   superConstructor.
>
> As an additional convenience, superConstructor will be accessible
>   through the constructor.super_ property.

In conclusion, you don't need to use `util.inherits` if you're using CoffeeScript's classes; just use the tools CS gives you, and you get bonuses like the `super` keyword.